# DOSBSOX-X 50 line display

Tags: dosbox

I am running DOSBox-x in Windows 10, screen resolution 3840 x 2160. Prior to updating to the latest version (release 0.83.15, July 1) I had been running it in 50 line mode which filled a large proportion of my screen and made it workable (adding 50 to my autoexec in dosbox-x.conf.)

I just updated to the new release and chose the option to retain my previous settings. However on launching the app it displays in a tiny box which is almost illegible and unworkable. I can just about see the 50 echoed to the startup screen.

Can anyone help me get back to a working DOSBox-x please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to make changes to the [sdl] and [render] sections of the .conf file:

```
[sdl]
fullscreen        = true
fulldouble        = false
fullresolution    = desktop
windowresolution  = original ...

[render]
aspect            = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved. I needed to make changes to the [sdl] and [render] sections of the .conf file.

Comment: It would be most helpful if you mentioned **what changes you made** to the *sdl* and *render* sections. Why not even include the whole configuration?